# SQL Server differences between same table on different databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the same table in two different databases. It has the same columns, primary keys, etc. but data in this table may differ from one database to another. So I am trying to get the differences. For example:

```
Database A                 Database B
  Table_A                    Table_B
```

Table_A and Table_B have Id1 and Id2 fields as primary key.

Table_A and Table_B is exactly the same but may contain different data. So I would like to obtain the differences, I mean, obtain the data that is in Table_A but not in Table_B, and insert them in Table_B, or if it is not possible to automatically insert them in Table_B to generate a list of inserts.

To obtain the data that is in Table_A and not in Table_B and vice versa, I do  the following:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM Table_A a
    FULL JOIN Table_B b ON (a.Id1=b.Id1 and a.Id2=b.Id2)
WHERE a.Id1 IS NULL OR b.Id1 IS NULL or  a.Id2 IS NULL OR b.Id2 IS NULL
```

Then I use excel to generate my inserts to be inserted on table Table_B.

Is that correct? or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario I would go with the [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement

```
MERGE INTO Table_B AS Trg
   USING (SELECT ID1, ID2, YourDataColumn FROM Table_A) AS Src
      ON Trg.ID1 = Src.ID1 AND Trg.ID2 = Src.ID2
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
   INSERT (ID1, ID2, YourDataColumn )
      VALUES (Src.ID1, Src.ID2, Src.YourDataColumn );
```

Comment: But this works if Table_A and Table_B are in the same database, right? but what happens if Table_A is in database_A and Table_B is in database_B? I mean tables in different databases.

Comment: You'll have to qualify your source table with the database, i.e. when executing the statement in database_B you have to use `database_A..Table_A`

Comment: Ok. Apart from merge into Table_B is it possible at the same time to classify the inserts and updates being performed into two other tables? I mean put inserts in a table, let's say, Inserted_Table, and updates in another table, let's say Updated_Table and finally deletes in another table, let's say Deleted_Table so at then end I know which rows have been inserted as news (Inserted_Table), which ones have been updated (Updated_Table) and which ones have been deleted (Deleted_Table). Using OUTPUT clause in Merge is it possible? If so can you provide and example?

Answer (score 0):

Would be great to know what database you're on. 
Oracle SQL Developer got tooling for this. http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/09/sql-developer-database-diff-compare-objects-from-multiple-schemas/

Comment: Since the OP tagged multiple versions of Microsofts SQL Server Oracle Tools won't be of much use here.